# App Script Google Sheet creating multiple PDFs from 20+ sheets without it timing out

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below which hides all tabs but the current and exports to a pdf in a specified drive folder. Then unhides all, cycles to the next and repeats. Works fine but want to be able to scale the tab to fit to one page.

Other methods using URLfetchapp allow for scaling but it causes time outs by too many requests.

```
function Exportpdf() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  nextSheet()
  exportSheet()
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()=='Data'){}
  else {Exportpdf()}
};

function nextSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numSheets = ss.getSheets().length;                // number of sheets
  var activeSheetIndex = ss.getActiveSheet().getIndex() - 1;   // see below 
  var newSheetIndex = (activeSheetIndex + 1) % numSheets;   // add 1; wrap around
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[newSheetIndex]);  
}

function exportSheet() {
var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== actualSheetName) {
sheets[i].hideSheet()
}
}
var pdfName = (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " - " + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName());
var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName));
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
sheets[i].showSheet()
}
newFile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById("11ZLhYZgpLuq5VWB90TdGbDrOUzP2SUlr"));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is the question?

Comment: The PDF it creates of the individual sheets is a 2 page pdf. I need a way to scale it to just 1 Thanks